# RCP command with Java is not working properly

Tags: java, unix

I am using RCP with Java to copy files from one server to another server. In my source server I have 10000 files (Each file size is 5 KB). I am using the below program to copy the same. But after copying few files, it is failing to copy the remaining files.

```
package com.rcp.tester;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyFile{
private static int successCounter = 0;
private static int failedCounter = 0;

public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i=1;i<=10000; i++){
        StringBuffer rcpCommand = new StringBuffer("rcp -pr <some path>");
        rcpCommand.append("Test"+i+".xml");
        rcpCommand.append(" <RemoteUserNAme>@<RemoteIp>:<RemotePath>");
        try{
            executeCommandLineArgument(rcpCommand.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception excep){
            excep.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private static void executeCommandLineArgument(String commandToBeExecuted) throws     Exception{
    Process process = null;
    try{
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToBeExecuted);
    }
    catch (IOException ioException){
        throw new Exception(ioException.getMessage());
    }
    try{
        process.waitFor();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException interruptedExcep){
        throw new Exception(interruptedExcep.getMessage());
    }
    int retVal = process.exitValue();
    if(retVal !=0 ){
        failedCounter++;
        System.err.println(" Failed to execute file numbered: "+failedCounter);
    }
    else{
        successCounter++;
        System.out.println(" Successfully copied file numbered:  "+successCounter);
    }
}

}
```

A. I have tried several times but could not get any reason. What could be the reason?
B. Is there any other way of coping the files except using **process**?

**EDIT**

Tried with the below shell script:

```
i=1
while [ $i -le 10000 ]
do
{
  echo "copying Test{$i}.xml"
  rcp -pr <some path>/Test$i.xml <RemoteUserNAme>@<RemoteIp>:<RemotePath>
  i=`echo $i+1|bc`
}
done
```

I have observed that exactly **510** files are being copied and afterwards below error message is getting printed:

**rcmd: socket: All ports in use**

Comment: Have u first tried rcp manually from shell?

Comment: Does the command produce any output? You are not doing anything with the output.

Comment: @Juned Yes, I have tried with the command manually. It is working fine. The problem is appearing if the number of files are more.

Comment: @immibis Not clear about what output you are referring. I am trying to copy the files from one server to another. I am expecting the same no of files in my destination server.

Comment: @Somnath when you run the command, manually, does it display anything?

Comment: From [HP Consumer Support](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c02662351), it seems to be I should have port number 514 to number 1024 be free in my local system. 

Is there any other way to handle this scenario.

Comment: @Somnath when you run the command manually, does it display anything?

Comment: @immibis No, when I tried from the shell, on successful copy it returns me the next line on the shell and the file got copied successfully.

Comment: Oops, I didn't see the error message "All ports in use error" - ignore my previous comments, this is nothing to do with unread output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the above problem.

In my server, only 510 ports were configured. Since I was invoking separate RCP command for each file, all ports were getting exhausted soon and I was getting **rcmd: socket: All ports in use** error.

Below link helped me on this:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c02662351

Another observation is after one minute all 510 ports were freeed automatically. So while coping, I make the current thread to wait for one minute and copied next set of 510 files and so on.

*However why the ports were freeed automatically after one minute is still not known to me.*